# Regular Expression in Python matching string of alphanumerics

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex in Python for the following pattern

- 6 digits (0-9)
- 1 Upper Case Letter (A, B, C or D)
- 2 digits (0-9)
- 1 Upper Case Letter (R)
- 2 digits (0-9)

Example: ***123456B01R02*** or Example: ***263956A01R04***

I am completely new to Regex and struggeling big time. I was trying `6[0-9]1[A-D]2[0-9]R2[0-9]` but of course it does not work.

Could anyone please give me some kickstart?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[0-9]` matches a digit, `[0-9]{6}` matches six digits. Do not forget to use the right `re` method: if you want to only match strictly that string format use `re.fullmatch`.

Comment: so then [0-9]{6}[A-D][0-9]{2}[R][0-9]{2} would be correct?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I tried the two examples and they match. Questioning myself if it matches all cases. How can I be sure?

Comment: Check your regex at http://regex101.com.

Comment: Looks good for the moment. I'll leave it like that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: /[0-9]{6}[A-D][0-9]{2}R[0-9]{2}/